# Git: overwrite all files in a repository from another commit

Tags: git

I have two branches. One is `develop` for development; the other branch is `passed` which will have test-passed commits from `develop`.

We will open a branch to develop a new feature and merge it back to branch `develop` when it's done, and we will test all new merged commits in `develop` by CI server.

When a test passes, we want to merge that commit into branch `passed` from `develop` and overwrite all files in the repository of old branch `passed`. That means, we want to do **overwrite**, not `merge`, and all files in the commits of the branch `passed` should be exactly the same to corresponding commits of the branch `develop`.

Branch `passed` tracks the test-passed commits and we will release the latest passed commit for beta testing.

The question is, **how to overwrite a branch but not merge into a branch from the branch `develop`**?

BTW, I want to keep two separated branches.

Comment: Your question indicates that you don't have a deep understanding of Git.  When you `git merge` your `passed` branch into `develop` you are overwriting the files, and this is one of the natural ways to do this in Git.  You have to make a commit, at least initially, to bring the changes from `passed` into `develop`.  Can you rephrase your question so that it is clear what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to have the `passed` branch point to *the exact same commit* as `develop` once the tests have passed.

You can do it with `git branch --force`:

```
git branch --force passed develop
```

Here's from [the `git branch` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> **-f**
>   **--force**
>   Reset <branchname> to <startpoint> if <branchname> exists already. Without -f git branch refuses to change an existing branch.

Comment: Thanks Enrico, but I need the two branches separately (like using `--no-ff` when `merge`), not make them have the same history. I want to track all passed commits in the `passed` branch.

Answer (score 0):

If this is REALLY what you want. You can delete the `passed` and create it again from `develop`, which will result `develop` to be the same as `passed`. But are you sure you want to do this? If yes, why don't you just add a tag to that commit in `develop`?

Comment: I don't want to delete the `passed` branch. The `passed` branch keeps tracking all passed commit from `develop` in his history but discard all changes created by `passed` branch itself.

Using tags is one solution. But I don't want to have too many tags automatically generated by Jenkins server. I have another Jenkins task to continuously monitoring the latest passed commit to release for beta testing. 

Maybe you have a solution about this and you can share this with me. :)